# PHP curl does not resolve local host names

Tags: php, curl, nginx

I am using multiple local hostnames defined in the hosts file of my Windows machine.

For example: localhost, admin_a, admin_b, etc.

I would like to execute curl through PHP on such local hostnames, however the execution hangs and no result is returned.

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, [ 'localhost:80:127.0.0.1']);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

I tried with the option CURLOPT_RESOLVE (not documented on php.net) and it does not seem to help.

On the other hand, the curl command line in a bash console works instantly:

```
curl http://localhost
```

What should I do to get PHP curl returns something on locally defined hostnames?

Server: nginx

**UPDATE**

The php console returns this:

```
Rebuilt URL to : http://localhost/
Trying ::1...
TCP_NODEDELAY set
Trying 127.0.0.1...
TCP_NODEDELAY set
Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Accept: */*
```

Then nothing happens, the page is just hanging returning nothing.

Comment: default protocol for the `CURLOPT_URL` isn't documented

Comment: You try `http://admin_a` in command-line and `admin_a` in PHP thus getting different results is not a surprise. Curl is not a consumer grade browser. You should not expect it to auto-correct or auto-complete anything.

Comment: curl cli sends `User-Agent` header so try it with `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` defined.

Answer (score 1):

by default, curl try to guess the protocol based on the url, and my best guess is, it fails to guess the protocol for `admin_a` - you can probably get the same problem if you change your curl command to `curl admin_a`, anyway, change your setopt to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://admin_a');` - or alternatively, explicitly tell curl what to use with CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL, eg `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL,'https');`

Comment: I get no result using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://admin_a');` The script hangs and nothing is returned

Comment: @Vincent strange, enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE and run it again, and make sure to log what goes to stderr (by default in nginx+php-fpm, stderr goes to nginx's error logs)

Comment: I did that and I have updated my answer with the message returned in the PHP console.

Comment: @Vincent that verbose log indicates that your localhost webserver is not responding.. does it work if you load http://localhost  in your web browser?

Comment: That is what exactly what I do not understand: if I access localhost in a separate tab, it works fine and return the proper message (a json string). I have 2 instances of php-cgi running, maybe it is an upstream issue with nginx. I don't where to look for anymore.

Comment: @Vincent i don't have time now, but i'll probably have this time tomorrow, and in 10 hours from now, could you contact me on facebook? if you catch me at a time i'm not busy, we could debug it together